# How to deal with Large number of ClusterItems in Cluster - Android GoogleMaps V2

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using GoogleMapsV2. I have around 10 000 cluster items which I bulk add to ClusterManager (ClusterManager.addItems(Collection).

My problem is that the clustering and de-clusterin process is lagging and slow. I believe it shouldn't be that slow with around 10 000 items. Testing on OnePlus3 (with 6GB or ram) so it's not the phone.

Here is cluster relate code in activity:

```
// Rent markers
rentMarkerList = new ArrayList<>();
rentClusterManager = new ClusterManager<OffersMarker>(this, gmap);
rentClusterRenderer = new OffersClusterRenderer(this, gmap, rentClusterManager);
    rentClusterManager.setRenderer(rentClusterRenderer);

for (AdMarker adMarker : adsArray) { //<-- adsArray.size() = 6500
    OffersMarker offsetItem = makeOffersMarker(adLocation, nrOfAds, realEstateAdIds, OffersMarker.DEALTYPE.SALE_CODE);
    rentMarkerList.add(offsetItem);
}

// Do bulk add of Markers into ClusterManager.
rentClusterManager.addItems(saleMarkerList);
rentClusterManager.cluster();
```

I went over my ClusterRenderer and I am not performing any large operations in onBeforeClusterItemRendered() and onBeforeClusterRendered().
It seems that the application is much slower when doing Clustering than it is in de-clustering but that may also be because clustering is done usually on a much smaller zoom level and thus more markers are displayed.

My android monitor shows that the clustering process alters the memory and CPU and not the GPU so it's not a graphics problem.

Solutions I tried:
Doing dynamic cluster rendering like described [here](https://discgolfsoftware.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/hiding-and-showing-on-screen-markers-with-google-maps-android-api-v2/). In this case you loop through your markers list and see which are in the Viewport bounds so you only display those markers. This made the whole thing worse because I had to loop through all the 10 000 markers every time onCameraIdle... was called.

Any ideas where to start optimizing this problem?

Comment: did you ever sort this out? I am having the same issue with 2000+ markers

Comment: I ended up creating a local SQLLight database which I kept updated on the background with all the 2000+ markers. I only rendered the markers that where in the viewport. Also check out this custom Kotlin library written to solve the problem. https://github.com/darwin-mirai/android-maps-utils

Comment: I also store in Room database + limit to current viewport, however I'd like to do what google maps does which is very efficiently decide what to render at each frame. I guess they use some kind of precalculation otherwise i find it impossible to go through so many markers in real time

Comment: Yes for my case, I also solved it using business rules where I just filtered the markers shown to the user at any single time. For a purely technical solution, it would require more research as I believe it needs a proprietary approach. Let me know if you manage to crack this, at the moment I didn't pursue a technical solution myself.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use `rentMarkerList` anywhere else? If not, you can refactor your code in this way:

```
rentClusterManager = new ClusterManager<OffersMarker>(this, gmap);
rentClusterRenderer = new OffersClusterRenderer(this, gmap, rentClusterManager);
rentClusterManager.setRenderer(rentClusterRenderer);

for (AdMarker adMarker : adsArray) { //<-- adsArray.size() = 6500
   rentClusterManager.addItem(makeOffersMarker(adLocation, nrOfAds, realEstateAdIds, OffersMarker.DEALTYPE.SALE_CODE));
}

rentClusterManager.cluster();
```

So you don't create an extra list of markers and don't add them all at the same time, but add them one by one.

You can also repleace foreach loop with simple for loop. According to this [Android performance patterns episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZOf3pOAM6A), it works faster.

I don't think that that will significantly improve the performance, it's just little optimization tips, that may help.

Answer (score 1):

There is implementation of a view-based clustering algorithm in [android-maps-utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) library that can be used for better performance of clustering.
I had 5000+ markers and clustering was struggling when zooming in and out. After setting Algorithm to NonHierarchicalViewBasedAlgorithm, clustering is very smooth and faster.

```
mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<>(this.mContext, mGoogleMap);

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
this.mActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
mClusterManager.setAlgorithm(new NonHierarchicalViewBasedAlgorithm<MyItem>(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels));
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a really clean and elegant solution. And it can be used also with Android Maps Compose: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose/issues/210#issuecomment-1855931489

Answer (score 0):

After straggling with 30K markers on ios i just dropped google cluster manager, it has very poor preformance and not scalable at all. there plenty other free cluster libs, just drop google-utiils.

I have swapped it for ClusterKit - works grate!
https://github.com/hulab/ClusterKit - (iOS)